# How to get count number of equal elements in two torch tensors that also equal a specific value

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm working in pytorch and trying to count the number of equal elements in 2 torch tensors, that also equal a specific value.

That is, if tensor a=[0,1,2,0,1,2] and tensor b = [0,2,1,0,2,1]

I want it to return:

- 3 when I check how many element are equal in the a,b and also equals 0. sum(a == b and a == 0 and b == 0) = 2,
- 0 when I check how many element are equal in the a,b and also equals 1 or 2. sum(a == b and a == 1,2 and b == 1,2) = 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Your last sentence is very unclear, please give a better example.

Comment: sorry, I edited. Is it clearer now?

Comment: But a and b only have two locations with "0" in the same place. Why do you expect 3 as a result?

Comment: sorry, I've meant 2... edited again

Comment: How about `torch.sum((a==b)*(a==0))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight forward approach would be:

```
torch.sum((a==b) * (a==val))
```

if `val` is the value you look for.